# Get document HTML before document.write();

Tags: javascript, html, pageload, document.write

I would like to be able to get a page's HTML as a string **before** the page loads and `document.write();` is called using my javascript extension. Is it possible to get some or all of a page's HTML before it loads? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

or that :

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Comment: are you sure this get the HTML **before** the page loads or doucment.write calls? I couldn't get it work that way

Answer (score 1):

Try load page using jQuery ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page.html",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            // in data is returned page.html html code
        }
    });
});
```

`document.documentElement.innerHTML` or `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will store page code loaded only before that script

Comment: I'm not quite sure this works. I tried using this code: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page.html",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
           var myWindow = window.open ("", "msgwindow", "width=200, height=100");
           myWindow.document.write(data + "hello world");
        }
    });
});` and yet the window opened _after_ the page loaded. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

document.write takes place before document.$( document ).ready() or document.onload.  A document.write after onload event (the signal the page has loaded) overwrites the document. So for setting portions of the page using javascript the best practice is general to use getElementById and write to it.

The only things available during document.write are those things above it in the document file, and it is not a document feature but rather a normal implementation.

IE

```
<p id="line1">1st line of html output</p>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById("line1").innerText);
</script>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById("lastline").innerText);
</script>
<p id="lastline">last line of html output</p>
```

Normally results in a alert box with "1st line of html output"

Followed by an error in console ... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

---

**An alternative solution** is to display:none the page. Modify the page then use a transaction effect to cause the page to be displayed. Which gives the same appearance to the user.

Comment: so if I'm reading this right, I can't access the HTML until it is visible unless I use a DOM manipulator? (like getElementByID etc.)

Comment: @WilkyRL Yes and no, you can by how it is implemented read html of what is above the script. Possibly document.write an absolute positioned element which appears above what has already been rendered. But, that may not be the method you are desiring to write the page in. Alternative you can use CSS3 transitions to render the page the way you want.